# JavaFX and Swing performance issues

Tags: java, swing, javafx, netbeans-plugins, jdk1.7

We have been having perpetual performance issues when running JavaFX inside a JFXPanel in Swing based applications.

This seems to only be a problem when running on JDK1.7, because whenever it is possible to run JDK1.8 this works perfectly without changing any code.

The symptoms are that the application seems to render fonts in a fuzzy way and also the performance is terrible (multiple seconds to respond to keypress when typing in a TextField).

We are observing the correct rules about EDT, AWT and Platform threads, so I doubt that this can be the issue.

We are stuck having to support JDK1.7 because this is a plug-in for NetBeans which some users will be running on JDK1.7 for various good reasons and we cannot force them to upgrade.

EDIT: Here is a MCVE which recreates the problem

```
package javaapplication3;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
       });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        Group  root  =  new  Group();
        Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        TextField  text  =  new  TextField();
        Label label = new Label();
        VBox box = new VBox();

        label.setText("This is a test label");


        box.getChildren().add(label);
        box.getChildren().add(text);

        root.getChildren().add(box);

        return (scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The tests we are performing have very simple javafx with e.g. only an AnchorPane with a TextField on it and absolutely no code behind it, and just typing in the TextField is painfully slow.

Behavior looks very much like lock contention between the Swing and JavaFX threads, but it does not seem like we can find any explanation or solution.

Comment: missing there invokeLater for EDT (the same as is there correctly - Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {), for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: I'm curious, what are these "various good reasons"?

Comment: All of the interesting code is shown. There are no events tied up and the application is doing nothing other than showing the TextField which placed on an AnchorPane using SceneBuilder.

Comment: @Cobusve: That's not the "interesting" code. If you want help for free, you should at least put some effort in it and provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you don't provide one, you may as well read [JavaFX for Swing Developers](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/jfxpub-swing.htm) and find the solution yourself.

Comment: I can post all the code for a MCVE but because of the complications of making a NetBeans plugin it will contain at least 11 files with hundreds of lines of boilerplate code, and that to me is not productive anymore. I will do it just for you and to prove that I am not being lazy :)

Comment: The good reasons are e.g. 70,000+ customers with 1.7JDK installed who do not want to upgrade right now. Some of them are running WindowsXP and cannot use JDK1.8 but have legacy hardware which cannot run on any other OS.

Comment: @Cobusve: all you need to provide is a Swing/JFXPanel and whatever you do with it. Just use the boilerplate code from the JavaFX for Swing Developers link I posted and add the relevant parts. That's the 1st step to find out yourself whether the problem is in Java 7 or if it's in your framework.

Comment: @Cobusve: The MCVE works fine for me in Java 7u65, Windows 7. No slowdowns during typing.

Comment: The slowdown is minor with such a small project, but still very noticeable on my machine. I have tested on 7u67 and 7u80 and get the same behavior. Of course which version of jfxrt did you link into the project? I am on a MAC, but behavior is the same on Windows machines.

Comment: I tested this on my Mac under JDK 7u65, with the JavaFX version included in the JRE, and I could not discern any slowdown while typing. FWIW though, even when Windows XP was a supported OS, I would have considered JavaFX as pretty much experimental on that platform, and certainly not production-ready. You're now talking about platforms (both XP and Java 7) that are not really supported: XP is completely without support, and Java 7 has ceased public updates. As a software developer, I would not certify any software I wrote on a system that was not supported by the system vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the answer that you are looking for, but since we have the same problem with Java 7 support, the answer is that Java 7 has reached its end of life:

> July 2015: Updates for Java 7 are no longer available to the public.
>   Oracle offers updates to Java 7 only for customers who have purchased
>   Java support or have Oracle products that require Java 7.

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml

There are no "good reasons" if problem solving is as easy as using a different java version. You don't break things by upgrading to Java 8.

Comment: I am accepting this because it looks like there is no other real solution than using 1.8, which works fine.